# Solitaire Java Program

Tags: java

Hey guys so I'm taking my first Java class ever and am stuck with an error code while trying to compile this program. I attached both classes hoping somewhere he can help me find the error. This is the error I'm receiving:

> Error: constructor Card in class Card cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: char,char
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

It shows the error is on the line "Card temp= new Card();" under the public void shuffle method. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Deck {

private Card [] data;



public Deck()

{

String suits = "HDSC";

String ranks = "A23456789TJQK";

data = new Card[52];



int count = 0;

Card C1;

for (int s = 0; s < suits.length(); s++){

for (int r = 0; r < ranks.length(); r ++)

{

C1 = new Card(ranks.charAt(r), suits.charAt(s));

data[count++] = C1;

}

}

}



//This function display's the whole deck of cards

// Our output should be as below

// AH 2H 3H ... KH

// AS 2H 3S ... KS

// AD 2D 3D ... KD

// AC 2C 3C ... KC



public void display()

{

int index=1;

for (int i=0; i<52; i++)

{

System.out.print(data[i].rank +"" + data[i].suit + " ");

if (index%13 == 0 && i!=0 )

System.out.println();

index++;

}

}



//This function randomly shuffles the deck of cards

public void shuffle()

{

int index;



Random random = new Random();



for (int i = 0; i<52; i++)

{

index = i + random.nextInt(52 - i);

Card temp= new Card();

if (index != i)

{

temp = data[i];

data[i] = data[index];

data[index] = temp;

}

}

System.out.println("Card Shuffled");

}



public void deal()

{

int sum = 0;

int countPrime = 0;

boolean isPrime = false;



for(int i=0; i<52; i++)

{

sum += data[i].getValue(data[i]);

isPrime = checkPrime(sum);



if (isPrime == true)

{

sum = 0;

countPrime++;



if (i==51)

{

System.out.println("Winner in " + countPrime + " Piles");

break;

}

}



if (i==51)

System.out.println("Loser");

}

}





boolean checkPrime(int num)

{

boolean isPrime = true;



for(int j = 2; j <= num/2; ++j)

{

// condition for nonprime number

if(num % j == 0)

{

isPrime = false;

break;

}

}



return isPrime;

}

//Display menu

public static int menu() {



System.out.println("\nWelcome to Solitaire Prime!");

System.out.println("1) New Deck");

System.out.println("2) Display Deck");

System.out.println("3) Shuffle Deck");

System.out.println("4) Play Solitaire Prime");

System.out.println("5) Exit");

Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

int choice = in.nextInt();



return choice;



}



public static void main(String args[])

{

Deck newDeck = null;

int choice;

do{

//Accepts user input for menu

choice = menu();



if (choice == 1)

{

newDeck = new Deck();

System.out.println("New deck created");

}



else if (choice == 2 )

{

newDeck.display();

}



else if (choice == 3 )

{

newDeck.shuffle();

}



else if (choice == 4 )

{

newDeck.shuffle();

newDeck.deal();

}



else if (choice == 5)

{

System.out.println("Exiting game. Goodbye!");

return;

}

else

System.out.println("Wrong choice! Please try again.");



}while(choice!=5);

}

}
```

```js
public class Card {

 char suit;
 char rank;

public Card(char r, char s)
{
rank = r;
suit = s;
}
public void menu()

{

}

public void display(Card C1)
{
char suit = getSuit(C1);
char rank = getRank(C1);
String suitName = "";
String rankName = "";

if (suit == 'S')
suitName = "Spade";

else if (suit == 'H')
suitName = "Hearts";

else if (suit == 'C')
suitName = "Clubs";

else if (suit == 'D')
suitName = "Diamonds";

if (rank == 'A')
rankName = "Ace";

else if (rank == '2')
rankName = "Two";

else if (rank == '3')
rankName = "Three";

else if (rank == '4')
rankName = "Four";

else if (rank == '5')
rankName = "Five";

else if (rank == '6')
rankName = "Six";

else if (rank == '7')
rankName = "Seven";

else if (rank == '8')
rankName = "Eight";

else if (rank == '9')
rankName = "Nine";

else if (rank == '1')
rankName = "Ten";

else if (rank == 'J')
rankName = "Jack";

else if (rank == 'Q')
rankName = "Queen";

else if (rank == 'K')
rankName = "King";

System.out.println(rankName + " of " + suitName);
}

//This method gives the value of a card
public int getValue(Card C1)
{
int value = 0;

if (C1.rank == 'A')
value = 1;

else if (C1.rank == '2')
value = 2;

else if (C1.rank == '3')
value = 3;

else if (C1.rank == '4')
value = 4;

else if (C1.rank == '5')
value = 5;

else if (C1.rank == '6')
value = 6;

else if (C1.rank == '7')
value = 7;

else if (C1.rank == '8')
value = 8;

else if (C1.rank == '9')
value = 9;

else if (C1.rank == '1')
value = 10;

else if (C1.rank == 'J')
value = 10;

else if (C1.rank == 'Q')
value = 10;

else if (C1.rank == 'K')
value = 10;

return value;
}

//This method gives the rank of a card
public char getRank(Card C1)
{
return C1.rank;
}

//This method gives the suit of a card
public char getSuit(Card C1)
{
return C1.suit;
}
}
```

Comment: `Card temp= new Card();` You don't have a constructor in the `Card` class that takes no parameters. You will either have to supply that call of the constructor with two `char` parameters, or define a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: How and where would I put that? Sorry it's only my second program so I realize this is probably a stupid question. But I do know what the  constructor looks like  public ConstructorCard()
 {
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Card` class only has a constructor that takes two `char` arguments; there is no zero-argument constructor defined.

When shuffling, you don't need to create a new instance of `Card` like you're currently doing here: `Card temp= new Card();` Instead of creating a new instance of `Card` and throwing it away, just assign the shuffled `Card` value to your `temp` variable like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<52; i++) 
{
    index = i + random.nextInt(52 - i);

    if (index != i)
    {
        Card temp = data[i];

        data[i] = data[index];

        data[index] = temp;
    }
}
```

Note that we moved `temp` into the if-block, since it's only used in that scope.

Comment: That makes sense thanks! I got it to compile but I am having another issue now though once I pick any of the menu options I receive this java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Deck.main(Deck.java:282)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)

Comment: The code I was given by my teacher to start this does have suit and rank as private char suit and private char rank under the Card class but I changed it to public because I was getting a compiler error with it could that be the cause at all?

Comment: A NullPointerException implies that you're calling a method on an object that is `null`, i.e. hasn't been instantiated (new'd) or assigned a value. For example, in your `main` method where you handle choices other than 1 (choice 2, for example), you call `display` on `newDeck`, which it will be `null` if you haven't ran choice 1 yet. Notice how in choice 1 you create a `Deck` using `newDeck = new Deck()`. If you run any of the other choices before choice 1, `newDeck` will still be null since you haven't assigned it anything yet.

Comment: got it! and lastly when I go to play solitaire it shows winner in the amount of piles or loser but doesn't actually print the cards that where played.